# Is there any way i can make my function add a row to my table?

Tags: javascript, html-table, row

im having issues with my code not inserting the information into my table, im new to programming and when i click the add button it should in my opinion insert the new information into the table. It seems like its inserting but it doesnt show on my screen or in the table. Im trying to make a table that can insert my schoolbooks into a table.

any tips or tricks?

```
<head>
    <style>
        table {
            font-family: arial, sans-serif;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }

        td,
        th {
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;
        }

        tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #dddddd;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <h2>Semester Books</h2>

    <table id="schoolBooks">

        <tr>

            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>E-book</th>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Programming Language</td>
            <td>2018</td>
            <td>yes</td>


        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Database Systems</td>
            <td>2000</td>
            <td>yes</td>


        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Algorithms and Data Structure</td>
            <td>1995</td>
            <td>no</td>


        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Programming in C++</td>
            <td>1999</td>
            <td>no</td>


        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Compiler Design</td>
            <td>2018</td>
            <td>yes</td>


        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <form onsubmit="addRow();return false">

        <div>
            <label for="title">Title:</label>
            <input type="text" id="aTitle" name="user_title" required="required" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{1,20}">



        </div>
        <br>
        <div>

            <label for="name">Year:</label>
            <select name="dropdown" id="aYear" name="user_year">
                <option value="1990">1990</option>
                <option value="1991">1991</option>
                <option value="1992">1992</option>
                <option value="1993">1993</option>
                <option value="1994">1994</option>
                <option value="1995">1995</option>
                <option value="1996">1996</option>
                <option value="1997">1997</option>
                <option value="1998">1998</option>
                <option value="1999">1999</option>
                <option value="2000">2000</option>
                <option value="2001">2001</option>
                <option value="2002">2002</option>
                <option value="2003">2003</option>
                <option value="2004">2004</option>
                <option value="2005">2005</option>
                <option value="2006">2006</option>
                <option value="2007">2007</option>
                <option value="2008">2008</option>
                <option value="2009">2009</option>
                <option value="2010">2010</option>
                <option value="2011">2011</option>
                <option value="2012">2012</option>
                <option value="2013">2013</option>
                <option value="2014">2014</option>
                <option value="2015">2015</option>
                <option value="2016">2016</option>
                <option value="2017">2017</option>
                <option value="2018">2018</option>
                <option value="2019">2019</option>
                <option value="2020">2020</option>

            </select>




        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            <label for="mail">E-Book</label>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" id="aYes" name="user_points" value="yes"> Yes<br>
            <input type="radio" id="bNo" name="user_points" value="no"> No <br>

        </div>

        <button type="submit"> Add </button>



    </form>
```

```
<script>
    function addRow() {
        var table =
            document.getElementById("schoolBooks");
        var row = table.insertrow(-1);
        var title = row.insertCell(0);
        var year = row.insertcell(1);
        var ebook = row.insertCell(2);

        var ebookValue = getRadioVal();
        var titleValue = document.getElementById("aTitle").value;
        var yearValue = document.getElementById("aYear").value;

        title.innerHTML = titleValue;
        year.innerHTML = yearValue;
        ebook.innerHTML = ebookValue;

    }

    function getRadioVal() {
        var ebookValue = "";
        if (document.getElementById("aYes").checked) {
            pointValue = document.getElementById("aYes").value;
        } else if (document.getElementById("bNo").checked) {
            pointValue = document.getElementById("bNo").value;
        }
        return ebookValue;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: There you go, just had some issues inserting the full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First issue ->

// You had to use e.preventDefault() to prevent the page
 from reloading when submitting the form
Second issue -> "insertrow" should be "insertRow" and "insertCell" should be "insertCell".

Code after correction:

```
<h2>Semester Books</h2>

<table id="schoolBooks">

      <tr>

            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>E-book</th>

      </tr>
      <tr>
            <td>Programming Language</td>
            <td>2018</td>
            <td>yes</td>


      </tr>

      <tr>
            <td>Database Systems</td>
            <td>2000</td>
            <td>yes</td>


      </tr>
      <tr>
            <td>Algorithms and Data Structure</td>
            <td>1995</td>
            <td>no</td>


      </tr>
      <tr>
            <td>Programming in C++</td>
            <td>1999</td>
            <td>no</td>


      </tr>
      <tr>
            <td>Compiler Design</td>
            <td>2018</td>
            <td>yes</td>


      </tr>
</table>
<br>
<form id="main_form">

      <div>
            <label for="title">Title:</label>
            <input type="text" id="aTitle" name="user_title" required="required" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{1,20}">



      </div>
      <br>
      <div>

            <label for="name">Year:</label>
            <select name="dropdown" id="aYear" name="user_year">
            <option value="1990">1990</option>
            <option value="1991">1991</option>
            <option value="1992">1992</option>
            <option value="1993">1993</option>
            <option value="1994">1994</option>
            <option value="1995">1995</option>
            <option value="1996">1996</option>
            <option value="1997">1997</option>
            <option value="1998">1998</option>
            <option value="1999">1999</option>
            <option value="2000">2000</option>
            <option value="2001">2001</option>
            <option value="2002">2002</option>
            <option value="2003">2003</option>
            <option value="2004">2004</option>
            <option value="2005">2005</option>
            <option value="2006">2006</option>
            <option value="2007">2007</option>
            <option value="2008">2008</option>
            <option value="2009">2009</option>
            <option value="2010">2010</option>
            <option value="2011">2011</option>
            <option value="2012">2012</option>
            <option value="2013">2013</option>
            <option value="2014">2014</option>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>
            <option value="2016">2016</option>
            <option value="2017">2017</option>
            <option value="2018">2018</option>
            <option value="2019">2019</option>
            <option value="2020">2020</option>

            </select>




      </div>
      <br>
      <div>
            <label for="mail">E-Book</label>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" id="aYes" name="user_points" value="yes"> Yes<br>
            <input type="radio" id="bNo" name="user_points" value="no"> No <br>

      </div>

      <button type="submit"> Add </button>



</form>
```

JS:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("main_form").onsubmit = function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      addRow();
}
function addRow() {
      var table = document.getElementById("schoolBooks");
      var row = table.insertRow(-1);
      var title = row.insertCell(0);
      var year = row.insertCell(1);
      var ebook = row.insertCell(2);

      var ebookValue = getRadioVal();
      var titleValue = document.getElementById("aTitle").value;
      var yearValue = document.getElementById("aYear").value;

      title.innerHTML = titleValue;
      year.innerHTML = yearValue;
      ebook.innerHTML = ebookValue;

}

function getRadioVal() {
      var ebookValue = "";
      if (document.getElementById("aYes").checked) {
            pointValue = document.getElementById("aYes").value;
      } else if (document.getElementById("bNo").checked) {
            pointValue = document.getElementById("bNo").value;
      }
      return ebookValue;
}
</script>
```